# Why does my Clock widget stop updating - using IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)

Tags: android, android-widget, clock, intentfilter

I'm trying to create a clock widget that updates once every minute.

I tried using the AlarmManager to send update requests, but I figured that would not be as accurate as using `IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)`

The widget loads perfectly, and updates for about 10 minutes or so using the ACTION_TIME_TICK IntentFilter... but then just stops updating.

Here's my AppWidgetProvider class

```
public class ClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    private final String TAG = "ClockWidget";

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    private final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "ClassicBlack_Prefs";

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onEnabled()");

        super.onEnabled(context);
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, 0);
        prefEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        prefEditor.putBoolean("isWatchfaceActive", true).commit();

        drawWatch(context);

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                {
                    drawWatch(ctx);
                }
            }
        };

        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate()");
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDisabled()");

        super.onDisabled(context);
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, 0);
        prefEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        prefEditor.putBoolean("isWatchfaceActive", false).commit();

        if (receiver != null)
        {
            context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    }

    private void drawWatch(Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawWatch()");

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, ClockWidget.class);

        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        Log.i("ExampleWidget", "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(allWidgetIds));

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetIds.length; i++)
        {
            DrawWatchFace drawWatchFace = new DrawWatchFace(context, null, true, 500);
            drawWatchFace.createWatchWidget();

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clock_widget_layout);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_canvas_imageView_small, drawWatchFace.getPalletBitmap());

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds[i], views);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Your process is being terminated. This is perfectly normal. When your process terminates, your receiver is destroyed, and you will no longer receive broadcasts.

You cannot register for `ACTION_TIME_TICK` in the manifest, which is the typical way of handling this.

I recommend that you go back to your `AlarmManager` approach.

Comment: Hmm - I have not put it in the manifest at all... just in the AppWidgetProvider Class.

Comment: @DeNitE: I understand that. You are calling `registerReceiver()`. This will only work while your process is running. Your process will not run forever, nor should it. For many broadcasts, you can register for them in the manifest, and receive them even if you do not have a running process. This is not possible for some broadcasts. `ACTION_TIME_TICK` is one such broadcast.

Comment: Interesting - so I guess most widgets just use the AlarmManager to ensure it continues to update? Is there a way to sync an alarm with the system clock evey minute?

Comment: @DeNitE: "so I guess most widgets just use the AlarmManager to ensure it continues to update?" -- I have no idea. "Is there a way to sync an alarm with the system clock evey minute?" -- you are welcome to ask `AlarmManager` to give you control at the beginning of the minute, based on the `Calendar` object that you use to build your event time to use with `set()` or `setExact()`. Or, use `AlarmManager` just to ensure that your process is running, and use `ScheduledExecutorService` for your once-a-minute logic. There may be other patterns as well; those are what come to mind.